# How to add postfix address that gets piped through script

Tags: postfix, configuration

I have a Debian server running postfix. In the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` there is this line:

```
mailbox_command_maps  = pcre:/etc/postfix/mailbox-pcre
```

The file `/etc/postfix/mailbox-pcre` contains lines like this:

```
/^action/       /usr/sbin/takeaction -q
/^filter/       /usr/bin/filter-special
/^archway/      /usr/bin/archway2
```

I have a new situation where I want all e-mails with a To: address starting with "tester" to be run through a Perl script. I added a *new* entry to the file /etc/postfix/mailbox-pcre` like so:

```
/^action/       /usr/sbin/takeaction -q
/^filter/       /usr/bin/filter-special
/^archway/      /usr/bin/archway2
/^tester/       /usr/bin/tester
```

I added this line and restarted postfix. When I send an e-mail to the `tester` e-mail address I am getting an "unknown user" error. So there must be something else I need to do so that postfix recognizes the `tester` e-mail address.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `tester` must defined as local user (either by listing as system user or define in [local_recipient_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_recipient_maps)).

Another solution is define your command in [alias_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps). For example

```
#main.cf
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, pcre:/etc/aliases.pcre

#pcre:/etc/aliases.pcre
/^tester/  "|/usr/bin/tester"
/^action/  "|/usr/sbin/takeaction -q"
/^filter/  "|/usr/bin/filter-special"
/^archway/ "|/usr/bin/archway2"
```

This answer inspired by [this thread](http://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=113204445008204&w=2)